# Import node to another XML document

Tags: xml, powershell

This is what i have so far but i get a `"The node to be inserted is from a different document context."` Error. Any ideas?

```
$xml = [xml](Get-Content "C:\IT\HowardCo\Compare\New.xml") 
$xmld = [xml](Get-Content "C:\IT\HowardCo\Compare\ConfigExport.xml") 
$newNode = $xml.ImportNode($xmld.SelectSingleNode("//SaleItem[SaleItemId=2]"), $true)
$xmld.DocumentElement.AppendChild($newnode)
$xml.Save("C:\IT\HowardCo\Compare\New.xml")
```

This is the XML that im trying to grab info from. Its a list of Items organized by `SaleItemID` Im trying to grab the item and the `Price1` under `RevenueCenter`. Any Help with this would be amazing.

```
<ConfigExport>
    <SaleItems>
        <SaleItem>
            <SaleItemId>2</SaleItemId>
            <AltItemId>0</AltItemId>
            <Description>*Torta Ahogada Combo</Description>
            <Description2/>
            <Division>2</Division>
            <Available>1</Available>
            <BarCode/>
            <Plu Id="0"/>
            <Function Id="0">Revenue</Function>
            <RevenueCenter Id="1" Name="La Cocina">
                <Price1>6.49</Price1>
                <Price2>6.49</Price2>
                <ItemAvailabilityByMode>
                    <Mode Id="1" Name="Here">
                        <Available>1</Available>
                    </Mode>
                    <Mode Id="2" Name="To Go">
                        <Available>1</Available>
                    </Mode>
                </ItemAvailabilityByMode>
            </RevenueCenter>
        </SaleItem>
    </SaleItems>
</ConfigExport>
```

Comment: I submitted an edit for your broken XML example.  You had a hanging open for a second SaleItem, and didn't close the SaleItems or ConfigExport.

Comment: Additionally it would be helpful if you submitted a sample of your initial content for new.xml

Comment: @MatthewWetmore Hey, the reason why the Saleitem is left open is because many more saleitem come after it. The XML is quite big. Also the New.xml would just be a blank document until it copies over specific SaleitemID. Thank you!

Comment: Having a well-formed initial example makes it easier for people to reproduce your issue and suggest concrete and complete answers.  You also need something in the new document to be able to import/append.  Starting with an entirely blank document will have a $null documentelement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your new.xml starts out something like this:

```
<ConfigExport>
    <SaleItems>
    </SaleItems>
</ConfigExport>
```

You seem to appending the node back into the same document you read it from in the first place with the next to last line - I assume that's not what you intended. Ambiguously defined variable names makes the code hard to read and debug.

Here's a simple re-write with clearer naming:

```
$importXml = [xml]( Get-Content "C:\IT\HowardCo\Compare\New.xml" )
$exportXml = [xml]( Get-Content "C:\IT\HowardCo\Compare\ConfigExport.xml" ) 
$node = $exportXml.SelectSingleNode( "//SaleItem[SaleItemId=2]" )
$newNode = $importXml.ImportNode($node, $true)
$importXml.DocumentElement.AppendChild($newnode)
$importXml.Save( "C:\IT\HowardCo\Compare\New.xml" )
```

In your original code, with naming like this, you might have more quickly seen that you were appending the `$newNode` into `$exportXml`.